# Tabitem visibility binding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to bind tab item visibility but it's nothing happening
here is my code

> `<TabItem Header="{Binding tabVisibility}">`

and in my view modal

```
public Visibility tabVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                return _visibility;
            }

            set
            {
                _visibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Comment: please confirm you havent missed binding your viewModel with your View.

Comment: Check the data context for the view where the tab is located :)

Comment: Also, debugging should be you #1 step- does the application enter into the tabVisibility get at all?

Comment: @AshokRathod that was the issue i solved it tankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
<TabItem Visibility="{Binding tabVisibility,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=TabControl}}">
```

Comment: Have you changed **Header** to **Visibility**

Comment: Can you post your code part? we need more information. now i updated the answer. try this

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. the problem is the property is in another view modal
it was my mistake